# How to bootstrap correlation using vectorised function applied to large matrix?

Tags: r, performance, correlation, statistics-bootstrap

I understand how to boostrap using the "boot" package in R, through the PDF for the package and also from these two examples on Stack, [Bootstrapped correlation with more than 2 variables in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66755182/bootstrapped-correlation-with-more-than-2-variables-in-r) and [Bootstrapped p-value for a correlation coefficient on R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51761415/bootstrapped-p-value-for-a-correlation-coefficient-on-r).

However, this is for small datasets ( 2 variables or a matrix with 5 variables). I have a very large matrix (1000+ columns) and the code I use to compute the correlation between every metabolite pair (removing duplicate and correlations with the metabolite itself) is:

```
  x <- colnames(dat)
 GetCor = function(x,y) cor(dat[,x], dat[,y], method="spearman")  
 GetCor = Vectorize(GetCor)


 out <- data.frame(t(combn(x,2)), stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
  mutate(v = GetCor(X1,X2))
```

I'm not sure how I can then alter this for it to be the function I pass to statistic in boot so

```
 boot_res<- boot(dat, ?, R=1000)
```

Or would I just need to obtain a matrix of  the bootstrapped p value or estimate depending on function code (colMeans(boot_res$t)) and get rid of the upper or lower triangle?

Was curious to know the most efficient way of going about the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `cor.test` to get theoretical *t*-values. We will use them for comparison with the *B* bootstrap *t*-values. (*Recall:* The *p*-value is the probability of obtaining test results at least as extreme as the result actually observed, under the assumption that the null hypothesis is correct.)

Here is a similar function to yours, but applying `cor.test` and extracting statistics.

```
corr_cmb <- \(X, boot=FALSE) {
  stts <- c('estimate', 'statistic', 'p.value')
  cmbn <- combn(colnames(X), 2, simplify=FALSE)
  a <- lapply(cmbn, \(x) as.data.frame(cor.test(X[, x[1]], X[, x[2]])[stts])) |> 
    do.call(what=rbind) |>
    `rownames<-`(sapply(cmbn, paste, collapse=':'))
  if (boot) {
    a <- a[, 'statistic']
  }
  a
}
```

We run it one times on the data to get a theoretical solution.

```
rhat <- corr_cmb(dat)

head(rhat, 3)
#          estimate  statistic    p.value
# V1:V2  0.06780426  2.1469547 0.03203729
# V1:V3  0.03471587  1.0973752 0.27274212
# V1:V4  0.05301563  1.6771828 0.09381987
```

#### Bootstrap

We can assume from the start that the bootstrap with 1000 columns will run for a while (`choose(1000, 2)` returns 499500 combinations). That's why we think about a multithreaded solution right away.

To bootstrap we simple repeatedly apply `corr_cmb` repeatedly on a `sample` of the data with replications.

We will measure the time to estimate the time needed for 1000 variables.

```
## setup clusters
library(parallel)
CL <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterExport(CL, c('corr_cmb', 'dat'))

t0 <- Sys.time()  ## timestamp before run

B <- 1099L
clusterSetRNGStream(CL, 42)
boot_res <- parSapply(CL, 1:B, \(i) corr_cmb(dat[sample.int(nrow(dat), replace=TRUE), ], boot=TRUE))

t1 <- Sys.time()  ## timestamp after run

stopCluster(CL)
```

After the bootstrap, we calculate the ratios of how many times the `abs`olute bootstrap test statistics exceeded the theoretical ones ([Ref.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/28725)),

```
boot_p <- rowMeans(abs(boot_res - rowMeans(boot_res)) > abs(rhat$statistic))
```

and `cbind` the bootstrap *p*-values to the theoretical result.

```
cbind(rhat, boot_p)
#          estimate  statistic    p.value     boot_p
# V1:V2  0.06780426  2.1469547 0.03203729 0.03003003
# V1:V3  0.03471587  1.0973752 0.27274212 0.28028028
# V1:V4  0.05301563  1.6771828 0.09381987 0.08208208
# V1:V5 -0.01018682 -0.3218300 0.74764890 0.73473473
# V2:V3  0.03730133  1.1792122 0.23859474 0.23323323
# V2:V4  0.07203911  2.2817257 0.02271539 0.01201201
# V2:V5  0.03098230  0.9792363 0.32770055 0.30530531
# V3:V4  0.02364486  0.7471768 0.45513283 0.47547548
# V3:V5 -0.02864165 -0.9051937 0.36558126 0.38938939
# V4:V5  0.03415689  1.0796851 0.28054328 0.29329329
```

Note that the data used is fairly normally distributed. If the data is not normally distributed, the bootstrap *p*-values will be more different.

To conclude, an estimate of the time needed for your 1000 variables.

```
d <- as.numeric(difftime(t1, t0, units='mins'))
n_est <- 1000
t_est <- d/(choose(m, 2))*choose(n_est, 2)
cat(sprintf('est. runtime for %s variables: %s mins\n', n_est, round(t_est, 1)))
# est. runtime for 1000 variables: 1485.8 mins
```

(Perhaps for sake of completeness, a single-threaded version for smaller problems:)

```
## singlethreaded version
# set.seed(42)
# B <- 1099L
# boot_res <- replicate(B, corr_cmb(dat[sample.int(nrow(dat), replace=TRUE), ], boot=TRUE))
```

---

*Data:*

```
library(MASS)
n <- 1e3; m <- 5
Sigma <- matrix(.5, m, m)
diag(Sigma) <- 1
set.seed(42)
M <- mvrnorm(n, runif(m), Sigma)
M <- M + rnorm(length(M), sd=6)
dat <- as.data.frame(M)
```

Comment: if at all possible, please could you clarify why you would calculate a one sided p value here? I think I am misunderstanding what the null hypothesis would be ( in my mind, that there is no difference between the original coefficient and that generated from bootstrapping)?

Comment: also unsure as to why the test statistic is used to calculate the p value rather than the coefficient estimate

Comment: @pemb_bex6789 Take a closer look at the common frequentist definition of a _p_-value in parentheses at the beginning, which is exactly what this answer is based on. Also note the reference given. To resolve your confusion, or if you want to learn more about bootstrapping, I recommend Davison, A. C., and D. V. Hinkley. 1997. _Bootstrap Methods and Their Application._ Cambridge University Press.

Comment: thank you for this, will look into the book - was wondering if there is a preference for obtaining p values following a bootstrap approach vs 95% CI?

Comment: @pemb_bex6789 Depends on one's preferences, or those of the journal. The matter is not trivial; bootstrap _p_-values and bootstrap CIs do not necessarily agree, since the latter can be asymmetric (and thus perhaps slightly more informative).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? It follows more or less the same lines as my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51761673/8245406) to the 2nd question you link to in your question.
Note that I have simplified the correlation code, `cor` accepts a data.frame or a matrix, so pass a two column one and keep one of the off diagonal correlation matrix elements.

```r
library(boot)

bootPairwiseCor <- function(data, i) {
  d <- data[i,]
  combn(d, 2, \(x) cor(x, method="spearman")[1,2])
}

dat <- iris[-5]
nms <- combn(colnames(dat), 2, paste, collapse = "_")

R <- 100L
b <- boot(dat, bootPairwiseCor, R)
b
#> 
#> ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP
#> 
#> 
#> Call:
#> boot(data = dat, statistic = bootPairwiseCor, R = R)
#> 
#> 
#> Bootstrap Statistics :
#>       original        bias    std. error
#> t1* -0.1667777  0.0037142908 0.070552718
#> t2*  0.8818981 -0.0002851683 0.017783297
#> t3*  0.8342888  0.0006306610 0.021509280
#> t4* -0.3096351  0.0047809612 0.075976067
#> t5* -0.2890317  0.0045689001 0.069929108
#> t6*  0.9376668 -0.0014838117 0.009632318

data.frame(variables = nms, correlations = colMeans(b$t))
#>                   variables correlations
#> 1  Sepal.Length_Sepal.Width   -0.1630634
#> 2 Sepal.Length_Petal.Length    0.8816130
#> 3  Sepal.Length_Petal.Width    0.8349194
#> 4  Sepal.Width_Petal.Length   -0.3048541
#> 5   Sepal.Width_Petal.Width   -0.2844628
#> 6  Petal.Length_Petal.Width    0.9361830
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

To use `cor.test`, change the bootstrap function to

```
bootPairwiseCorTest <- function(data, i) {
  d <- data[i,]
  tests_list <- combn(d, 2, \(x) cor.test(x[[1]], x[[2]], method="spearman"), simplify = FALSE)
  sapply(tests_list, `[[`, "estimate")
}
```

And call with

```
b2 <- boot(dat, bootPairwiseCorTest, R)
```

Comment: was wondering, how I would do this using cor.test instead of cor in the above, I've been trying a few things now such as bootcorfun <- function(data, i){
  d <- data[i,]
  t(combn(names(d),2, \(x) cor.test(d[[x[1]]], d[[x[2]]], method="spearman")))
}, and keep coming up with incorrect number of subscripts on matrix or with other attempts invalid subscript type list.